# Approximation algorithm for minimising $x_i+y_i$ for monotonically increasing sequence $x_i$ and monotonically decreasing sequence $y_i$

Tags: approximation-algorithms, oracles

This is a cross-post from a [question I asked on cs.stackexchange 2 weeks ago](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154215/approximation-algorithm-for-minimising-x-iy-i-for-monotonically-increasing-se) with no answers. I thought it might find home here.

We are given sorted $0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_n$ and $y_1 \geq y_2 \geq \dots \geq y_n \geq 0$ non-negative **integers** accessible through oracles, with the additional constraints $x_{i+1}-x_i \leq 1$ and $y_i - y_{i+1} \leq 1$. Can we approximate the minimum of $x_i + y_i$ with $o(n)$ oracle queries to $x_i$, $y_i$ values, or is $\Omega(n)$ required?

For the exact case, a simple adversarial example can prove that you need to check all $n$ indices to find the minimum exactly (described in the link above).

A $2$-approximation can be taken by returning the index $i$ that minimizes $|x_i-y_i|$. This can be done using binary search using $O(\log n)$ queries.

**Can we do better than a $2$-approximation in $o(n)$?**

Comment: For completeness, worth adding a brief argument for the 2-approximation, maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theorem 1.** *For any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximation algorithm that makes $O(\epsilon^{-1}\log n)$ queries.*

Note that if $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small but constant,
the algorithm makes $O(\log n)$ queries.

Before we prove the theorem, we prove the following utility lemma:

**Lemma 1.** *Let $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_m$ be a partition of the indices $[n]$, and for each $\ell\in [m]$ let $a(\ell)$ be a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate solution to the subproblem induced by $P_\ell$.  That is,*
$$x_{a(\ell)} + y_{a(\ell)} \le (1+\epsilon) \big(\min_{i\in P_\ell} x_i + y_i\big).$$
*Let $a(\ell^*)$ be the best of these approximation solutions.  That is,
$\ell^* = \arg\min_\ell \{x_{a(\ell)} + y_{a(\ell)}\}$.  Then $a(\ell^*)$ is a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate solution to the original problem.*

*Proof.*  For any $i\in[n]$, we have, for $\ell$ such that $i\in P_\ell$,
$$x_i + y_i
 \ge (x_{a(\ell)} + y_{a(\ell)})/(1+\epsilon)
 \ge (x_{a(\ell^*)} + y_{a(\ell^*)})/(1+\epsilon).~~~~~\Box$$

Now we prove the theorem.  Here is the algorithm.  First, using a single binary search on $x_i/y_i$, find $h = \max\{i\in [n] : x_i / y_i \le 1\}$.  (Note that $x_i/y_i$ is increasing with $i$, so this takes $O(\log n)$ queries.)

Now partition the index set $[n]$ into two parts: $\{1, \ldots, h\}$ and $\{h+1, \ldots, n\}$.  First compute a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate solution to the subproblem induced by the first part $\{1, \ldots, h\}$ as follows.

Fix integer $k = \lceil 1/\epsilon\rceil$.
Using $k-1$ binary searches, partition the index set $[h]$ into $k$ parts, where, for each $\ell\in [k]$, each index $i$ in the $\ell$th part $P_\ell$ satisfies
$$(\ell-1)/k \le x_i / y_i \le \ell/k.$$
[For intuition, note that this condition is equivalent to
$$y_i (1+(\ell-1)/k) \le x_i + y_i \le y_i(1 + \ell/k),$$
so that within the part we have
$$x_i + y_i = (1+O(1/k))(1+(\ell-1)/k) y_i,$$
that is, the value $(1+(\ell-1)/k) y_i$ is a $(1+O(\epsilon))$-approximation to $x_i + y_i$.]

Now, for each $\ell\in [k]$, let $a(\ell)$ be the index $i$ in the $\ell$th part $P_\ell$ minimizing $y_i$.  Note that $y_i$ is non-increasing with $i$, so we can just take $a(\ell) \gets \min P_\ell$, without doing additional queries.

Note that $a(\ell)$ is a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate solution to the subproblem induced by $P_\ell$, because for any $i\in P_\ell$ we have
$$x_i + y_i
 \ge y_i(1+(\ell-1)/k)
 \ge y_{a(\ell)}(1+(\ell-1)/k)
 \ge (x_{a(\ell)} + y_{a(\ell)})\alpha(k, \ell),$$
where
$$\alpha(k, \ell) = \frac{1+(\ell-1)/k)}{1+\ell/k}
 = \frac{k+\ell-1}{k+\ell}
 = 1 - \frac{1}{k+\ell}
 \ge 1- \frac{1}{k+1}
 = \frac{1}{1+1/k}
 \ge \frac{1}{1+\epsilon}.$$

By Lemma 1, this gives us a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate solution to the first part $[h]$ of $[n]$, using $O(\epsilon^{-1} \log n)$ queries.  Similarly (exchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$) we can compute a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate solution to the second part $[n]\setminus[h]$ using $O(\epsilon^{-1} \log n)$ queries.  By Lemma 1, taking the best of these two solutions gives us a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate solution to the original problem, in $O(\epsilon^{-1} \log n)$ queries.$~~~\Box$

Comment: Really nice idea. I'm assuming the intuition for it is using the $2-$approximation idea (of $x_i$ being close to $y_i$) to get a refinement where $x_i$ is "close enough" to $y_i$ in one of the subintervals? Thank you.